# 403 Forbidden Error. Hosting a website on my PC with WAMP?

Tags: wamp

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate 64-Bit and have WAMP installed, nothing configured though. I'm using dynamic IP address. I have some web files that i want to host temporarily on my PC so that others can access it.

After turning all the services on and putting the server online, i get "Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server" when i type the external IP address of my machine. though it works with "localhost" and "127.0.0.1" rightly points to the www folder. Port 80 is opened and Windows firewall is disabled.

What is the problem? Where does my external IP address points on the server and how can i change it to the desired directory?

Comment: Most ISPs blovk port 80 inbound.  You also need to set up port forwarding on your router.

Comment: @SLaks If that was the case he would most likely not get that error, unless something else is hosting a web service on that port that is inaccessible externally. Regardless this is not a question for stackoverflow.

Comment: I checked Port 80 using PF Port Checker. It says it is Opened.

Answer (score 7):

First, check that the 'Put Online' worked properly, it may not have, if you have manually altered the default state of this section of httpd.conf file.

look at httpd.conf, when it is set ONLINE and it should say :-

For Apache versions 2.2.x

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
```

For Apache versions 2.4.x

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Require all granted
```

Change it manually if it does not.

Also if you have setup vhosts check the definition you created for `ServerName localhost` and make sure that is also set the same.

PS.
While quick and easy this does open your whole WAMP Apache server up to access from external address's.
It would be better to create a VHOST for your site so you can allow access to that from anywhere but keep the basic WAMP area safe and accessible from only localhost.

When you say you are entering the external IP Address of your machine, if you mean the WAN ip address i.e. the routers external address, most home routers do not allow `loop back` which would be required to make that work. So try accessing it from your smart phone ( while not connected to your router) or go to a friends and try it from there that will be your only accurate test of whether your config is working.

Comment: Thanks for this. This is the first place I've seen that informed me that Apache 2.4.X used a different format. Trying your suggestion worked perfectly. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

After replacement of

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

with  this

```
AllowOverride None
Allow from all
```

restart all services and make sure that you have put in online(left click on wamp icon and last option put online).

It's solved my 403 forbidden error.