# WampServer 3.0.4: 403 Forbidden while "Put Online"

Tags: wampserver

I try to access my localhost from another pc, through IP address in the same network (`10.0.0.6`). When I type this address in the pc that runs wamp, I can access - but when I do it in my laptop or smartphone, I get this 403 message:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

I am using WampServer 3.0.4 as mentioned above, Apache/2.4.18 (Win64) PHP/5.6.19 and MySQL/5.7.11 on Windows 10 (64 bit) with AVAST Antivirus and using "Test Mail Server Tool" on port 25.

I already tried these Q&A and didn't worked:

- [WAMP 403 Forbidden message on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204902/wamp-403-forbidden-message-on-windows-7)
- [403 Forbidden Error. Hosting a website on my PC with WAMP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173351/403-forbidden-error-hosting-a-website-on-my-pc-with-wamp)

I also tried few tutorials, one of them is [this one](https://www.digifloor.com/simple-steps-fix-403-forbidden-errors-wamp-server-28) and, of course, tried the "put online" button, which changed one line in `httpd.conf` from `Require local` to `Require all granted` automatically when I pressed it but still nothing, on the laptop and smartphone.

What else can I do? I just upgraded from 2.5 to the latest release on their website (late but finally). it's really frustrating me... any help or idea?

**p.s: I don't have static IP for localhost to access from another device, because my ISP not allowing it (it costs money) so I'm using dynamic ip or using my pc name in order to access. in wamp2.5 it worked well**

**UPDATE: I tried to disable AVAST Firewall for 10 minutes, and it doesn't show 403 anymore, but also doesn't show anything else (only timeout error). perhaps it's the firewall?**

Thank you all and, again, excuse me for my english (if I had any misspellings)

Comment: Duplicate of this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38347450/2310830

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes! Solved. Thank you very much!!